# Modules: IntelliJ vs. Maven

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

The concept of modules is not part of standard Java. IntelliJ defines a module as "a part of a project that you can compile, run, test and debug independently."

I am wondering if this concept in IntelliJ is borrowed from somewhere, or is it restricted to IntelliJ. Specifically, are IntelliJ modules equivalent to Maven modules?

Comment: No, they are different.  You can use IntelliJ without Maven.  Those projects will have one or more IntelliJ modules.  If you happen to be using Maven, IntelliJ and Maven modules may map 1:1.  I'm not sure about chronology or priority.  I first became aware of JetBrains in 2001.  I don't know which one used the term first.  It's a common enough idea.  I believe they were independent.